# Как редактировать индексную страницу Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Вообще проблема в том, что слайдер, который работает в Elementor, не работает в публикации. Стал смотреть логи и среди ошибок лишь одна, стал искать вхождение строки в VS Code но все они находятся в файлах с cache. Почему так, почему я не могу отредактировать напрямую или править этот скрипт в шаблоне. Но сколько бы я не искал, всё есть только в кеше.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где эта самая `button` которая Вам нужна? И что это за лиснер? Вы его добавляли?

Comment: Потому что редактирование индексной страницы (а ещё не к ночи упомянутым элементорм) осуществляется через админку, а не лазится в код. А код  (в который раз!) нужно показывать кодом. а не картинками

Comment: @SeVlad Спасибо!

Comment: @Simon Это сайт клиента, че он там добавлял одному богу известно. Мы лишь правки делаем, обычно привык всё через файлы делать, видимо с Элементором так не прокатит

Comment: Если это добавлялось через элементор, то логично и редактировать это через элементор

Comment: >"Привык всё через файлы делать" @ViVi, научись работать с CMS. "Через файлы" в движках делаются другие вещи (упрощёно: то, что нельзя сделать через админку. И это сильно упрощёно..)